# c++ jsoncpp: How to know location of incorrect JSON data when json parsing with try/catch?

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

There is lots of data in JSON, and **I don't want to use IsInt() or IsUInt()** when getting data from JSON. Are there any tips for finding the incorrect key (which is an inappropriate key)?

ex)

```json
{
    "a": 0,
    "b": -1, 
    ..... (large data)
}
```

```cpp
try {
    value["a"].asUInt();
    value["b"].asUInt(); // type error
    ..
}
catch{
    // how to know "b" is problem?
}
```

I don't want to use typecheck befause of performance issue

Comment: Oh boy, an XY problem! ;)  "finding the inappropriate key" sounds like an XY problem. 
 What are you actually trying to do?  My first reaction is, don't put the access of "a" in the try block (have a separate try block for "a"), then you'll know that "b" was the problem.  Also, [jsoncpp will convert to UInt](https://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/json__value_8cpp_source.html#l00719) by checking the type anyway and throwing an exception if it's out of range, so why avoid that?  What's your "performance issue"?